# Converting a SQL query to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

How can we write below query's equivalent in LINQ ?

```
SELECT          
<<Columns>>         
FROM <<SOME JOINS>>         
AND  ISNULL(t.invoiceTypeID,0) NOT IN (2,3)          

AND EXISTS          
(   
     SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM <<Table name >> WHERE <<Condition>>          
)          

AND NOT EXISTS          
(   
     SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM <<Table name >> WHERE <<Condition>>          
)

AND NOT EXISTS          
(
     SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM <<Table name >> WHERE <<Condition>>        
)
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried do far? You should look at `Any` and `All` for `EXISTS` queries...

Comment: ye, I tried Any(), however not sure if it is yielding correct output

Comment: Well you haven't told us *how* you're using `Any`... and surely you should check whether or not you've got a problem before asking for help.